# "Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required" in VSCode, but works in R Studio

Tags: r, windows, visual-studio-code, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm having trouble trying to set up rmarkdown to work within VSCode.
I have tried `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = "path")`, but if I set it to the same path that R Studio successfully uses, if I do `rmarkdown::pandoc_available()` it still returns `[1] FALSE`.

I have also tried setting it as an environment variable in my VSCode settings.json. Again, I can knit with no problems from R Studio. I have looked at many answers to similar questions here on StackOverflow, but none of them have worked for me thus far. I am running Windows 10.

EDIT:
`r$> Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")`
Returns
`[1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc.exe"`

I have tried running
`Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc.exe")`

My settings.json file includes this

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": { "RSTUDIO_PANDOC":"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc.exe" }
```

Comment: Can you add these to your question? 1. Result of running `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")` in RStudio; 2. The complete path you are using in this line `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = "path")`; 3. The line you have tried adding to your `settings.json`.

Comment: @andycraig I've added them!

Comment: Thanks! Can you try running this in VS Code? `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc.exe"); Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC"); rmarkdown::find_pandoc()`

Comment: The first gives me [1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc.exe", and the second gives me $version [1] '0', so it didn't find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the pandoc folder to your `Path` environment variable:

1. Press Windows key and type 'environment variables'. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should take you to a window titled 'Environment Variables'
2. Select 'Path' and click 'Edit...'
3. You should see a list of paths. Click 'New' and enter `C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\quarto\bin\tools\`. It should be at the bottom of the list
4. Click 'Okay'

This is based on https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/289, which I interpret as advising to use the `Path` environment variable rather than the `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` environment variable when outside RStudio.

Comment: Good detective work! Thank you for finding that where I could not!